# How to expose templates from a C++ to C# via C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I want to expose a C++ library to a C# application and I decided to take the C++/CLI wrapper approach instead of P/Invoke. The problem that I am now facing is how to expose a templated class in the C++ lib to the C# application using generics.
On the C++ side I have:

```
template <typename T> class Someclass;
```

And my goal is to be able to expose the following type to the C# app

```
class Someclass<T> {}
```

So the question now is how should my C++/CLI wrapper look like. I tried the naive approach and created a templated type in C++/CLI and naturally I wasnt able to instantiate the class in C# with generic parameters. And if I expose the class as a generic class I wont be able to pass it to C++.

**Disclaimer:** I am a C++ newbie so please be gentle :)

I am familiar with the differences between generics and templates so no need to explain those. I have this bad feeling that what I want isn't doable, but since I am relatively new to C++ I hope I can somehow achieve it.

Comment: All template type arguments must be known at link time.  Short from a giant switch statement on all the T's that you want to support, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK: You'll have to write a C++ generic.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcligenerics.aspx

I don't see how the C# application would even understand the template being as that is calculated at compile time, so the C# application wont see templates in the DLL.